# Area of an elliptic?

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus

I'm looking for an **analytic way** to calculate the area of an elliptic described by $${x^2 \over a^2} + {y^2 \over b^2}=c^2$$
I saw it before, but now i've forgotten. I remember we set $x=a \cos x$ and $y=a \sin x$ but I don't remember what we did after that!

Comment: [Google](http://math.ucsd.edu/~wgarner/math20b/area_ellipse.htm) is your friend.

Comment: I presume that by "an analytic way", you mean a method _not_ involving calculus?

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Hmm, I assumed it meant "not geometric"; whatever that means...

Comment: @DavidMitra: Don't you think we should have $1$ instead of $c^2$? Or, I am missing something?

Comment: @BabakS. I missed that. But we can always divide through by $c^2$ assuming it's non-zero.

Comment: I think he probably means to calculate it as an integral with polar coordinates.

Comment: Ah, good old [Archimedes](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~mjunge/40611/Pr1.pdf). I should have known. (I haven't checked the link for accuracy.)

Comment: Yes, a variable change is a good idea. Simply set $T(x,y):=(x/a,y/b)$. Then this linear map $T$ transforms the surface enclosed by the ellipse into the closed disk of radius $c$ centered at $0$. So if the ellipse are is $A$, we have $|\det T| A=\pi c^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly, if you are looking for a calculus approach, you can do it by assuming:
 $$x=ac\cos(t),~~y=bc\sin(t),~~~c\neq 0$$ in which $0\le t\le 2\pi$ (Here, I am assuming @David's comment) and then follow the integral: $$S=\frac{1}2\int_0^{2\pi}(xy'-yx')dt$$

Note that others may use $S=\int_0^{2\pi}xy' dt$ instead.

Answer (score 2):

[It is not clear to us what you mean by analytic, esp with the tags of geometry and algebra-precalc]

The approach I'd use, is to consider the unit circle, and think about how much you need to stretch it in the $x$ and $y$ direction, in order to get an ellipse.

> Starting from the unit circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, we need to stretch it by $\frac{a}{c} $ in the $x-$ direction and $\frac{b}{c} $ in the $y-$ direction, to get the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = c^2$.
>  How does this change the area of the unit circle, which is $\pi1^2$?

Comment: That logic happens to work for area, but fails for the perimeter, so I wouldn't call it a proof.

Comment: @nbubis Yes, it doesn't work for perimeter, because when lengths get stretched they don't simply change by the ratio. Whereas, this is true for the area of figures, e.g. triangles.

Comment: Is there a deeper reason why areas correctly "warp" whereas perimeters don't?

Comment: @nbubis The deeper reason is from calculus. If you are looking at the graph $y=f(x)$, then the area is $ \int y \, dx$ and the perimeter is $\int \sqrt{ 1 + y' ^2 } \, dx$. If you stretch it in the y-direction to $ y_1 = a f(x)$, then $\int y_1 \, dx = a \int y\, dx$. However, you can see that the constant doesn't pull out in the perimeter: $\int \sqrt{ 1 + y_1 ' ^2} \, dx = \int \sqrt{ 1 + a^2 y' ^2 } \, dx \neq a \int  \sqrt{1 + y'^2 }\, dx$.